# Grouping objects and applying operation to the group

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Forgive me for my perhaps naive questions, I am beginning to discover Tikz potentials.  To ease certain operations as moving objects or transforming them, I want to know if there is a mechanism in Tikz that I can group certain operations and  give a name to this grouping and use that name in doing operations on the whole collection of objects that are grouped.  My first guess was perhaps **scope** will do this.  But could not see how I can refer collectively to the scoped operations and/or  objects.
The best analogy, for give me to mention it, is the grouping operation in Power Point.
Thanks for your help.
Artimess

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part [of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 12):

You can apply transformations to a `scope`, like for example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[rotate=45]
        \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
        \draw (0,0) circle (1);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Whatever parameters and operations you specify in the `[...]` at the beginning of the `scope` environment is applied to every command inside the `scope`.

Comment: I do not think that it answers OP's question. The scope is not named - no possibility to reuse it later.

Answer (score 10):

`TikZ 3.0` introduced a new concept called `pic`. It's possible to include complex drawing commands inside a `pic` and later use it as a whole. A little example with Caramdir's code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    mycomplexfigure/.pic = {
        \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
        \draw (0,0) circle (1);
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path  (1,3) pic{mycomplexfigure};
\path[red,rotate=45,transform shape]  (2,1) pic{mycomplexfigure};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some more examples with `.pic`:

- [Tikz pic parameter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173569/tikz-pic-parameter)
- [How do I draw a little red square to label my right triangle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154351/how-do-i-draw-a-little-red-square-to-label-my-right-triangle/154357#154357)
- [How to create something like a function (procedure, macros, etc.) in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172484/how-to-create-something-like-a-function-procedure-macros-etc-in-tikz/172821#172821)
- [How can I draw a TikZ element multiple times against a shaded background?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126161/how-can-i-draw-a-tikz-element-multiple-times-against-a-shaded-background/151772#151772)

Answer (score 1):

tikzpicture envionments can be nested. They behave like scope environments and support optional arguments for parameters. For instance, `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape] ... \end{tikzpicture}` could be used inside a parent tikzpicture environment.

Comment: I know that this works, but is it meant to work?  I ask because in another question (which escapes me now), an answer was to nest tikz pictures but when I experimented then I found that the inner and outer pictures didn't properly know about each other (in particular, node names and co-ordinates couldn't be guaranteed to work).

Comment: I used it but don't remember problems. But I wished also tikz matrices could be nested.