# How do I draw a little red square to label my right triangle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

The sample code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  ( 0 , 0 ) coordinate (A) 
    -- ( 4 , 0 ) coordinate (C) 
    -- ( 0 , 3 ) coordinate (B) 
    -- (0,    0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The figure:

[image: Right Triangle]

I would like to use a box in the lower left angle of the triangle to indicate a right angle.

Comment: Hi Stuart, welcome to the site! There's been a similar question before: [Insertion of perpendicular symbol at intersection of two perpendicular lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/insertion-of-perpendicular-symbol-at-intersection-of-two-perpendicular-lines)

Comment: Excellent, very helpful link. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 15):

With the help of the new library `angles` of TikZ 3.0.0 and a small patch, it is possible to get:

[image]

thanks to:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  ( 0 , 0 ) coordinate (A) 
    -- ( 4 , 0 ) coordinate (C) 
    -- ( 0 , 3 ) coordinate (B) 
    -- ( 0 , 0 )
    pic [draw,blue,thick,angle radius=0.5cm]  {squared angle = A--C--B}
    pic [draw,red,thick,angle radius=0.5cm]   {squared angle = C--A--B}
    pic [draw,green,thick,angle radius=0.5cm] {squared angle = C--B--A};
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  pics/squared angle/.style = {
    setup code  = \tikz@lib@angle@parse#1\pgf@stop,
    background code = \tikz@lib@angle@background#1\pgf@stop,
    foreground code = \tikz@lib@squaredangle@foreground#1\pgf@stop,  
  },
  pics/squared angle/.default=A--B--C,
  angle eccentricity/.initial=.6,
  angle radius/.initial=5mm
}

\def\tikz@lib@squaredangle@foreground#1--#2--#3\pgf@stop{%
  \path [name prefix ..] [pic actions]
  ([shift={(\tikz@start@angle@temp:\tikz@lib@angle@rad pt)}]#2.center)
    |-
  ([shift={(\tikz@end@angle@temp:\tikz@lib@angle@rad pt)}]#2.center);
  \ifx\tikzpictext\relax\else%
    \def\pgf@temp{\node()[name prefix
      ..,at={([shift={({.5*\tikz@start@angle@temp+.5*\tikz@end@angle@temp}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/angle
            eccentricity}*\tikz@lib@angle@rad pt)}]#2.center)}]}
    \expandafter\pgf@temp\expandafter[\tikzpictextoptions]{\tikzpictext};%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  ( 0 , 0 ) coordinate (A) 
    -- ( 4 , 0 ) coordinate (C) 
    -- ( 0 , 3 ) coordinate (B) 
    -- ( 0 , 0 )
    pic [draw,blue,thick,angle radius=0.5cm]  {squared angle = A--C--B}
    pic [draw,red,thick,angle radius=0.5cm]   {squared angle = C--A--B}
    pic [draw,green,thick,angle radius=0.5cm] {squared angle = C--B--A};
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The desired output seems to have the box filled in red as well as a label, hence let's use the `quotes` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  pics/squared angle/.style = {
    setup code  = \tikz@lib@angle@parse#1\pgf@stop,
    background code = \tikz@lib@angle@background#1\pgf@stop,
    foreground code = \tikz@lib@squaredangle@foreground#1\pgf@stop,  
  },
  pics/squared angle/.default=A--B--C,
  angle eccentricity/.initial=.6,
  angle radius/.initial=5mm
}

\def\tikz@lib@squaredangle@foreground#1--#2--#3\pgf@stop{%
  \path [name prefix ..] [pic actions]
  ([shift={(\tikz@start@angle@temp:\tikz@lib@angle@rad pt)}]#2.center)
    |-
  ([shift={(\tikz@end@angle@temp:\tikz@lib@angle@rad pt)}]#2.center);
  \ifx\tikzpictext\relax\else%
    \def\pgf@temp{\node()[name prefix
      ..,at={([shift={({.5*\tikz@start@angle@temp+.5*\tikz@end@angle@temp}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/angle
            eccentricity}*\tikz@lib@angle@rad pt)}]#2.center)}]}
    \expandafter\pgf@temp\expandafter[\tikzpictextoptions]{\tikzpictext};%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  ( 0 , 0 ) coordinate (A) 
    -- ( 4 , 0 ) coordinate (C) 
    -- ( 0 , 3 ) coordinate (B) 
    -- ( 0 , 0 )
    pic [draw,fill=red,angle radius=0.5cm,angle eccentricity=2,
    "$90^\circ$" {black,font=\footnotesize}]   {squared angle = C--A--B}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: "Small patch" is the understatement of the day.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig: a suggestion: make a diff of the original library; the change concerns only two lines of code.

Comment: Can this be made to work when the sides are not axis-aligned?

Comment: @NeilG: of course it should be possible, but very complex. Basically, you have to change the `|-` in `([shift={(\tikz@start@angle@temp:\tikz@lib@angle@rad pt)}]#2.center)
    |-` so that the first part of the path would be orthogonal to the base line of the triangle.

Comment: Have you considered to submit your code to be included in `angles` library?

Comment: @Ignasi: no, I haven't. However, I remember there were some problems: definitely more tests would be needed.

Answer (score 11):

For this simple case, you can just draw a square at `(A)`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  ( 0 , 0 ) coordinate (A)
    -- ( 4 , 0 ) coordinate (C)
    -- ( 0 , 3 ) coordinate (B)
    -- (0,  0);
\draw [fill=red](A) rectangle ++(0.5,0.5) node[above right]{$90^\circ$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To make it a little more general you could use relative coordinates, i.e. `\draw [fill=red](A) rectangle ++(0.5,0.5)`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Good point, Thanks and edited. :)

Answer (score 7):

This is an approach simplified by »[tkz-euclide](http://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide)«, which is mentioned indirectly in the comment to your question. Wherever the points are located that define the triangle, the right angle will be marked automatically.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,3){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(4,0){C}
    \tkzMarkRightAngle[draw=red,fill=red](B,A,C)
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For details please refer to the package manual, which is unfortunately only available in French.

---

[image]

Answer (score 7):

> **Note :** Since version 3.1 of TikZ `right angle` is part of the standard `angles` library. It works in the same way as `angle` pic.

This answer is very close to the answer of @ClaudioFiandrino, which is a slight modification of the standard `angles` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  pics/right angle/.style = {
    setup code  = \tikz@lib@angle@parse#1\pgf@stop,
    background code = \tikz@lib@rightangle@background#1\pgf@stop,
    foreground code = \tikz@lib@rightangle@foreground#1\pgf@stop,
  },
  pics/right angle/.default=A--B--C,
  angle eccentricity/.initial=.6,
  angle radius/.initial=5mm
}

\def\tikz@lib@rightangle@background#1--#2--#3\pgf@stop{%
  \path [name prefix ..] [pic actions, draw=none] (#2.center)
    -- ++(\tikz@start@angle@temp:\tikz@lib@angle@rad pt)
    -- ++(\tikz@end@angle@temp:\tikz@lib@angle@rad pt)
    -- ++(\tikz@start@angle@temp:-\tikz@lib@angle@rad pt)
    -- cycle;
}

\def\tikz@lib@rightangle@foreground#1--#2--#3\pgf@stop{%
  \path [name prefix ..] [pic actions, fill=none, shade=none]
  ([shift={(\tikz@start@angle@temp:\tikz@lib@angle@rad pt)}]#2.center)
  -- ++(\tikz@end@angle@temp:\tikz@lib@angle@rad pt)
  -- ++(\tikz@start@angle@temp:-\tikz@lib@angle@rad pt);
  \ifx\tikzpictext\relax\else%
    \def\pgf@temp{\node()[name prefix
      ..,at={([shift={({.5*\tikz@start@angle@temp+.5*\tikz@end@angle@temp}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/angle
            eccentricity}*sqrt(1/2)*\tikz@lib@angle@rad pt)}]#2.center)}]}
    \expandafter\pgf@temp\expandafter[\tikzpictextoptions]{\tikzpictext};%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw  (4,1) coordinate (C)
        -- (0,0) coordinate (A)
        -- ([turn] 0,3) coordinate (B)
        -- cycle
        pic [draw,red,"$\cdot$",angle eccentricity=.5]   {right angle = B--A--C}
        pic [draw,blue,thick]  {right angle = A--C--B}
        pic [fill=green,draw] {right angle = C--B--A};
        ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note :** I have created a `rightangles` library, available at [GitHub](https://github.com/kpym/tikz-rightangles) that can be used in place of this hack like this

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{rightangles, quotes}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw  (4,1) coordinate (C)
        -- (0,0) coordinate (A)
        -- ([turn] 0,3) coordinate (B)
        -- cycle
        pic [draw,red,"$\cdot$",angle eccentricity=.5]   {right angle = B--A--C}
        pic [draw,blue,thick]  {right angle = A--C--B}
        pic [fill=green,draw] {right angle = C--B--A};
        ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Best answer! The main one does not work for rotated angles! ;)

Answer (score 6):

This is how. Take the (A) as your reference point. Then (1) `yshift` to move the starting point up a little; (2) `xshift` to determine the end point; (3) connect these two points using -| (going horizontally and then vertically to the end point.)
[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  ( 0 , 0 ) coordinate (A) 
    -- ( 4 , 0 ) coordinate (C) 
    -- ( 0 , 3 ) coordinate (B) 
    -- (0,  0);
%\draw [red]([yshift=0.5cm]A) -| node[above right]{$90^\circ$}; % generates red line
\draw [fill=red]([yshift=0.5cm]A) -| node[above right]{$90^\circ$} ([xshift=0.5cm]A) 
-- (A) -- cycle ;   % if path is used, the square becomes invisible.
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How could one label the vertices, please? (Say by a letter X)

Comment: Is there a way to use a simple command, rather than drawing it? 
In my more complicated figures the triangles are rotated and drawing is a hassle, especially if I want to go back and change anything.

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora -- Use node technique as shown here\draw ([yshift=0.5cm]A) -| node[above right]{$90^\circ$} ([xshift=0.5cm]A){}; Same idea applies to the triangle tips.

Comment: @StuartRCarter -- Please refer to Jake's comment and take a look, to see if his 3-point command is what you need.

Answer (score 4):

With PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
    \pstGeonode[CurveType=polygon,PosAngle={-90,0,90}](1,1){A}(5,1){B}(1,5){C}
    \pstRightAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]{B}{A}{C}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]