# Drawing a line segment of a specific length that is perpendicular to a given line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a typical geometric construction that I want to draw using `TikZ`.  The following code gives a line segment `PQ`.  How do I get `TikZ` to draw a point on the line perpendicular to `PQ` and through `P` that is `2\sqrt{2}` units below the line segment `PQ`?  I think that I have to have `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` in the preamble to do this.  (I want to label this point R and draw right triangle `QPR`.)  If I want to use `\tkzMarkRightAngle(Q,P,R);` to indicate that the triangle is a right triangle, do I have to have `\usepackage{tkz-euclide}` in the preamble?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,intersections,quotes}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[yellow, line width=0.1pt] (-1.75,-1.75) grid[xstep=0.5, ystep=0.5]  (2.75,1.75);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,1.75) +(0,0.25cm) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-1.75) -- +(0,-0.25cm);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-1.75,0) +(-0.25cm,0) -- (2.75,0) -- +(0.25cm,0) node[below right] {$x$};

\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]left:$P$}] (P) at (-1,-1) {};
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt, label={[fill=white]right:$Q$}] (Q) at (2,1) {};

\draw[green!20!white] (P) -- (Q);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does [How do I draw a little red square to label my right triangle?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154351/13304) help?

Comment: Check page 145 of the manual (calc ltikzlibrary).

Comment: @John Kormylo I made the grid more expansive and included the code `\coordinate (R) at ($(P)!2\sqrt{5}!90:(Q)$);` and got an error message. It seems to me that TikZ could not interpret `\sqrt{5}` as part of a measurement.  I changed the command to `\coordinate (R) at ($(P)!1!90:(Q)$);` and nothing was plotted.  I think that I need to have `cm` as the units.  Isn't `cm` the default unit assigned to a number?
I changed the command to `\coordinate (R) at ($(P)!1cm!90:(Q)$);` and nothing was plotted.

Comment: @John Kormylo  I would like to have a dot put at R.  Why isn't `\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]above left:$R$}] (R) at R {};` putting a dot at R?

Comment: @John Kormylo By the way, how do I know whether -90 or 90 will make the coordinate R below line segment PQ?

Comment: @Claudio Fiandrino  I have to wait until I get the code for drawing this right triangle before I can use the code at the web site you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Check the code for explanatory comments:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

%% you need the following 2 lines to use \tkzMarkRightAngle
%\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
%\usetkzobj{all}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,intersections,quotes,calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[yellow, line width=0.1pt] (-1.75,-5) grid[xstep=0.5, ystep=0.5]  (2.75,1.75);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,1.75) +(0,0.25cm) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-1.75) -- +(0,-0.25cm);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-1.75,0) +(-0.25cm,0) -- (2.75,0) -- +(0.25cm,0) node[below right] {$x$};

\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]left:$P$}] (P) at (-1,-1) {};
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt, label={[fill=white]right:$Q$}] (Q) at (2,1) {};

\draw[green!20!white] (P) -- (Q);

%% the perpendicular
\pgfmathparse{2*sqrt(5)}
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]left:$R$}] (R) at ($ (P)!\pgfmathresult cm! -90:(Q) $) {};
\draw[green!20!white] (P) -- (R) -- (Q);


%% right angle with tkz-euclide
%\coordinate (p) at (P);
%\tkzMarkRightAngle[color=green!20!white](Q,p,R)
%\fill (p) circle (2.1pt);  %% to make the dot above right angle again.

\coordinate (a) at ($ (P)!5mm! -45:(Q) $);
\draw[green!20!white] (a) -- ($(P)!(a)!(Q)$);
\draw[green!20!white] (a) -- ($(P)!(a)!(R)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I understand that the command \coordinate (a) at ($ (P)!5mm! -45:(Q) $); is instructing `TikZ` to put a coordinate on the graph and to call it "a." With -45, isn't the command instructing TikZ to put the point at a distance of 5mm from P and at an angle of 45 degrees in the clockwise direction from line segment PQ?

Comment: @user74973 Yes.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions, tikz runs almost everything through pgfmathparse which looks more like C code: 2*sqrt(5) which BTW is over 4cm at the default scale.  ($(P)!1!90:(Q)$) means start at (P) and go 1 times the distance to (Q) 90 degrees (counter-clockwise) from the direction to (Q).

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,intersections,quotes,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[yellow, line width=0.1pt] (-1.75,-1.75) grid[xstep=0.5, ystep=0.5]  (2.75,1.75);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,1.75) +(0,0.25cm) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-1.75) -- +(0,-0.25cm);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-1.75,0) +(-0.25cm,0) -- (2.75,0) -- +(0.25cm,0) node[below right] {$x$};

\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]left:$P$}] (P) at (-1,-1) {};
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt, label={[fill=white]right:$Q$}] (Q) at (2,1) {};

\draw[green!20!white] (P) -- (Q);

\coordinate (R) at ($(P)!2cm*sqrt(5)!-90:(Q)$);
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt, label={[fill=white]right:$R$}] at(R) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: calc usage]

Comment: You said that  "($(P)!1!90:(Q)$) means start at (P) and go 1 times the distance to (Q) 90 degrees (counter-clockwise) from the direction to (Q)."  This code will give me a right triangle.  Right?  It won't be the one intended - it will draw the height from the base PQ at Q.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are not forced to use `\usepackage{tkz-euclide}`. It only gives you an easier `\tkzMarkRightAngle(Q,P,R)` construct than pure `tikz`, but this can also be achieved relatively easily using only `tikz` as @HarishKumar did it. Also, using `style`s for axes and points makes the code cleaner.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}\small

\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt,p/.style={circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt},ax/.style={draw=gray!50,latex-latex}]
\draw[yellow,line width=0.1pt] (-2.75cm,-1.75cm) grid[xstep=0.5, ystep=0.5]  (2.75cm,1.75cm);
\draw[ax](0,1.75cm) +(0,0.25cm) node[above] {$y$} -- (0,-1.75cm) -- +(0,-0.25cm);
\draw[ax](-2.75cm,0) +(-0.25cm,0) -- (2.75cm,0) -- +(0.25cm,0) node[right] {$x$};
\coordinate[p,label={[fill=white]below:$P$}] (P) at (-1cm,-1cm);
\coordinate[p,label={[fill=white]right:$Q$}] (Q) at (2cm,1cm);
\coordinate[p,label={[fill=white]left :$R$}] (R) at ($(P)!{2cm*sqrt(2)}!90:(Q)$);
\draw (P)--(R)--(Q)--(P)--cycle;
\coordinate (a) at ($(P)!4mm!45:(Q)$);
\draw ($(P)!(a)!(Q)$) -- (a) -- ($(P)!(a)!(R)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I looked on page 216 of the manual at `http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf` and it only says that specifying coordinates follows `at`.  Now, you tell me that you can locate a point with `$(P)!{2cm*sqrt(2)}!90:(Q)$`.  That will be helpful in coding.  Thanks.

Comment: I see how you got a length of 2\sqrt{2} - you scaled 2cm by \sqrt{2}.  Isn't the default unit centimeters?  Why can't you get the same picture with `$(P)!{2*sqrt(2)}!90:(Q)$`?

Answer (score 1):

For those who are interested, a way (among others) of doing it with [MetaPost](https://www.tug.org/metapost.html).

The point R such that PR is perpendicular to PQ and located `2\sqrt{2}` units away from P below PQ, is given by the following instruction (`u` being the unit length, here `cm`):

```
 R = P + 2u*sqrt2*unitvector(Q-P) rotated -90;
```

The `anglebetween` macro of MetaPost's [Metafun](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/MetaFun) format allows to draw right angle marks quite easily between the two intersecting segments `P--Q` and `P--R` (the third argument being the label, here an empty string), if the `anglemethod` parameter is set to 2. With the default value of this parameter, 1, the mark would be a circular arc. The desired length of the mark should be given as argument to another parameter, `anglelength` (which defaults to 20 pt).

```
  anglemethod := 2; anglelength := 2mm;
  draw anglebetween(P--Q, P--R, "");
```

See [the Metafun manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf), p. 279, for a detailed presentation.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibsetformat{metafun}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    % Axes parameters
    u := cm; % Unit length
    xmin := -1.75u; xstep := .5u; xmax := 2.75u; 
    ymin := -5u; ystep := xstep; ymax := 1.75u;
    % Triangle summits
    pair P, Q, R; P = u*(-1, -1); Q = u*(2, 1); 
    R = P + 2u*sqrt2*unitvector(Q-P) rotated -90;
    beginfig(1);
      % Grid
      drawoptions(withcolor yellow);
      for i = ceiling(xmin/xstep) upto floor(xmax/xstep):
        draw (i*xstep, ymin) -- (i*xstep, ymax);
      endfor 
      for j = ceiling(ymin/ystep) upto floor(ymax/ystep):
        draw (xmin, j*ystep) -- (xmax, j*ystep);
      endfor
      % Axes
      drawoptions(withcolor .8white);
      drawarrow (xmin, 0) -- (xmax, 0); 
      drawarrow (0, ymin) -- (0, ymax); 
      % Triangle
      drawoptions(withcolor green);
      path triangle; triangle = P--Q--R--cycle; draw triangle;
      % Right-angle mark of length 2 mm (and no label)
      anglemethod := 2; anglelength := 2mm;
      draw anglebetween(P--Q, P--R, "");
      % Labels
      drawoptions();
      label.bot("$x$", (xmax, 0)); label.lft("$y$", (0, ymax));
      dotlabel.lft("$P$", P); dotlabel.rt("$Q$", Q); dotlabel.bot("$R$", R);
    endfig;
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

To be typeset with LuaLaTeX. Output:

[image]