# TikZ angles library incompatible with 3d library?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3d, tikz-angles

I recently discovered the `angles` TikZ library which is very convenient when one needs to annotate angles.

I encountered a problem when I tried to use it in with the `3d` library, since the arc is drawn without using the defined canvas plane. Here is an illustration (the alpha angle should be plotted as the green arc):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[blue,->] (0,0)coordinate(O) --  (1,0,0)node[below right]{$\vec{x}$};
    \draw[blue,->] (O) --  (0,1)node[above]{$\vec{y}$};    
    \draw (2,0) coordinate (A) -- (0,0) coordinate (B) -- (1,1) coordinate (C);
    \draw[red] pic ["$\alpha$", draw, ->] {angle};
\end{tikzpicture}

\def\w{40} \def\aa{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={({cos(\w)*1cm},{-sin(\w)*sin(\aa)*1cm})},
        y={({sin(\w)*1cm},{cos(\w)*sin(\aa)*1cm})},
        z={(0,{cos(\aa)*1cm})}]
    \draw[blue,->] (0,0,0)coordinate(O) --  (1,0,0)node[below right]{$\vec{x}$};
    \draw[blue,->] (O) --  (0,1,0)node[above]{$\vec{y}$};    
    \draw[blue,->] (O) --  (0,0,1)node[above]{$\vec{z}$};

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
        \draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (1);
        \draw (2,0) coordinate (A) -- (0,0) coordinate (B) -- (1,1) coordinate (C);
        \draw[red] pic ["$\alpha$", draw, ->] {angle}; % incorrect
        \draw[green] (0:0.6) arc (0:45:0.6); % correct 
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: exemple]
Is there a simple hack to have it work correctly?

Note that there is no problem with the `right angle` command, since the plot consist in parallel segments.

Comment: Use `tikz-3dplot` for angles in three dimensions.

Comment: @HenriMenke `transform shape` is sufficient. Internally `tikz-3dplot` also does nothing but drawing arcs. You only have to make sure the `angle` `pic` knows which coordinate system to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `transform shape`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[blue,->] (0,0)coordinate(O) --  (1,0,0)node[below right]{$\vec{x}$};
    \draw[blue,->] (O) --  (0,1)node[above]{$\vec{y}$};    
    \draw (2,0) coordinate (A) -- (0,0) coordinate (B) -- (1,1) coordinate (C);
    \draw[red] pic ["$\alpha$", draw, ->] {angle};
\end{tikzpicture}

\def\w{40} \def\aa{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={({cos(\w)*1cm},{-sin(\w)*sin(\aa)*1cm})},
        y={({sin(\w)*1cm},{cos(\w)*sin(\aa)*1cm})},
        z={(0,{cos(\aa)*1cm})}]
    \draw[blue,->] (0,0,0)coordinate(O) --  (1,0,0)node[below right]{$\vec{x}$};
    \draw[blue,->] (O) --  (0,1,0)node[above]{$\vec{y}$};    
    \draw[blue,->] (O) --  (0,0,1)node[above]{$\vec{z}$};

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
        \draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (1);
        \draw (2,0) coordinate (A) -- (0,0) coordinate (B) -- (1,1) coordinate (C);
        \draw[red] pic ["$\alpha$", draw, ->,transform shape] {angle}; % correct
        \draw[green] (0:0.6) arc (0:45:0.6); % correct 
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also transform the angle arc but not the text.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[blue,->] (0,0)coordinate(O) --  (1,0,0)node[below right]{$\vec{x}$};
    \draw[blue,->] (O) --  (0,1)node[above]{$\vec{y}$};    
    \draw (2,0) coordinate (A) -- (0,0) coordinate (B) -- (1,1) coordinate (C);
    \draw[red] pic ["$\alpha$", draw, ->] {angle};
\end{tikzpicture}

\def\w{40} \def\aa{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={({cos(\w)*1cm},{-sin(\w)*sin(\aa)*1cm})},
        y={({sin(\w)*1cm},{cos(\w)*sin(\aa)*1cm})},
        z={(0,{cos(\aa)*1cm})}]
    \draw[blue,->] (0,0,0)coordinate(O) --  (1,0,0)node[below right]{$\vec{x}$};
    \draw[blue,->] (O) --  (0,1,0)node[above]{$\vec{y}$};    
    \draw[blue,->] (O) --  (0,0,1)node[above]{$\vec{z}$};

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
        \draw[dashed] (0,0) circle [radius=1];
        \draw (2,0) coordinate (A) -- (0,0) coordinate (B) -- (1,1) coordinate (C);
        \draw[red] pic ["$\alpha$", draw, ->,transform shape,angle radius=0.8cm,
        pic text options={transform shape=false}] {angle}; % correct
        \draw[green] (0:0.9) arc[start angle=0,end angle=45,radius=0.9]; % correct 
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about `transform shape`, and your trick to not transform the text is welcome. Any chance to see such a modification natively implemented in the angles library someday, as @Kpym did [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409550/46718)?

Comment: @Tobard The `right angle` is already part of the `angles` library, see the example on p. 569 of pgfmanual v3.1.5. Which changes would you like to implement? (You can also use `\draw[red] pic ["$\alpha$" {transform shape=false}, draw, ->,transform shape,angle radius=0.8cm,] {angle};` to not project the text on the plane.)

Comment: Yes, the `right angle` is part of the `angles` library. My point is that `right angle` works natively in a `3d` picture, but it is not the case for `angle` as one may expect. It should be great to improve the `angle` macro to work in that situation as well, avoiding to use the hack you proposed.

Comment: @Tobard It is the purpose of the `transform shape` key to make a `pic` or a `node` pick up the ambient transformation, which they by default do not. If you want to project a node text on the plane, you need to say `transform shape` as well. It is a design choice by Ti*k*Z, which one may argue about. But comparing adding the prescription of adding `transform shape` to Kpym's code, I may want to call the other one the "hack", yet this is a matter of taste. You can just build the `transform shape` key in the definition of your personal `angle` key, is this what you want?

Comment: It seems to me that the purpose of the `angles` library is to facilitate angles annotation with less code and more readability. Under this hypothesis, following the 3d projection while keeping text intact seem to be the logical result and would be worth implementing it. For now, I will then create my own macro. Thanks.

Comment: @Tobard Fair enough. You could also just say `\tikzset{pics/angle/.append style={/tikz/transform shape,/tikz/pic text options={transform
  shape=false}}}` to add this prescription to all angles.